# How to print a nice table format with awk together with it's column (NF) and row number (NR)?

Tags: awk

Sample data

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk {print} file.txt 
a b
b c
c d
wolf@linux:~$
```

It's easy to do this as the data is very small.

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk 'BEGIN {print "  " 1 " " 2} {print NR,$0}' file.txt
  1 2
1 a b
2 b c
3 c d
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is there any similar solution for bigger data? I'm thinking to use something like `for loop` on `BEGIN {print "  " 1 " " 2}` part instead of printing out the header manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BEGIN` section is executed before any input file is open so running a `for loop` there would do you no good as the first line of input hasn't been read yet so you don't know how many fields there are to loop over. Unless you add a `getline` but that's a whole other can of worms (see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline).

I'd let `awk` create the fields content and then let `column` format it for spacing, e.g.:

```
$ awk '
    NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " %s", i; print "" }
    { print NR, $0 }
' file  | column -s' ' -t
   1  2
1  a  b
2  b  c
3  c  d
```

If your input file could have multiple blanks or tabs between fields then just change the last line of the awk script from `{ print` to `{ $1=$1; print`.

Answer (score 1):

We can generate tables using a groff wrapper `tbl`, which generates groff code to generate tables according to the architecture required.

Here, based on the data, we generate dynamically the code for tbl utility which shall generate the code for groff typesetting utility, using the awk utility:

```
< file \
awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS = "@"
    print ".TS"
    print "box,tab(", ");"
  }

  !NF {next}

  NR==1 {
    fx(" ", "c", "c", ".")
    fx(OFS) 
  }

  { $1 = NR OFS $1 };1

  END { print ".TE" }

  function fp(str, sep) {
    printf "%s%s", sep, str
  }

  function fx(sep, a, b, c,   i) {
    fp(a)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      fp(b""?b:i, sep)
    fp("\n", c)
  }
' - | tbl - | groff -Tascii | grep .
```

---

**Output:**

```
+----------+
|    1   2 |
|1   A   B |
|2   B   C |
|3   C   D |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to iterate over the fields. NR is the current line number, NF is the number of fields on this particular line.

```
{   printf ("%4d", NR);
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; ++f) printf (" %-6s", $f);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

For the header, you need to wait for the first row to discover how many column you need to label. So this goes *before* preceding code. Note it prints f itself as a label, instead of $f, which represents the field content.

```
NR == 1 {   printf ("%4d", NR);
    for (f = 1; f <= NF; ++f) printf (" %-6s", f);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

You need to find the maximum field width to keep the alignment. Each %-6s means "a string field, left aligned, and padded up to 6 chars with spaces".

Edit: for a more advanced version, you can store all the data in a 2-D array, indexed by [NR, NF], and output them in an END block. Then you can do two further things:

(1) For each column, find the maximum width of any cell, and fix up the %-10s format with the actual width for that column.

(2) For each column, if it has all numeric values, fix up its %s to right-justify the values.

Comment: nit-pick: `print ""` is generally better than `printf ("\n")` as it uses the value of `ORS` rather than hard-coding the value that you hope `ORS` is set to.

Comment: @EdMorton Good comment. I have had people take the "" out of my posted code because "it doesn't output anything anyway", and then tell me I'm printing $0 somehow, so I standardise on printf. I'm also prone to writing data to stdout or with > or |, and text errors to stderr, so I never mess with ORS. I define (and comment) in BEGIN e.g. NUL for \0 line termination. I admire awk's defaults for brevity, not so much for readability. And I write awk with semi-colons and as much else of C as I can, because otherwise I get syntax errors every time I switch between them.

Comment: The OS messes with ORS for you. On some systems RS and ORS will both be `\r\n` and in those cases `print ""` will do what you want while `printf "\n"` will corrupt the output. You could write `printf "%s", ORS` I suppose. IMHO potential readability issues with awk are minor and easily avoided, unlike some other languages (https://www.zoitz.com/comics/perl_small.png) :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't so much mean the code was hard to read, more that the defaults would surprise novices: recent examples include a newline between the pattern and action parts of a statement; and declaring an initialiser outside of a BEGIN block; and a print command without any args.

Comment: @EdMorton Luckily (for me), I have been glued to *nix for 40 years, except for a single Microsoft GUI-based project around 1995. So my only concern has been cleaning up messy M$ files, not preserving their idiosyncrasies. `sub(/(\r)?$/)` and `RS="(\r)?\n"` have been my only friends. Reading .xlsx files in awk was a breakthrough.

Comment: `sub(/(\r)?$/,"")` = `sub(/\r$/,"")`. I wouldn't use `RS="(\r)?\n"` as it'll corrupt files that have `\r\n` record endings and contain solitary `\n`s within fields such as Excel would create in exported CSVs when cells contain newlines. So you can't use `RS="\r?\n"` if you don't know what the line endings are since that could be corrupting the records that do end in `\r\n`, and if you do know what the line endings are then you'd use just `RS="\r\n"` or `RS="\n"` as appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to write a single awk script that will robustly handle files that could have either `\r\n` or `\n` line endings. Even a file with `\n` line endings could have `\r` as the last char of the last field so seeing `\r\n` at the end of each line doesn't even  guarantee you're dealing with a file that has `\r\n` line endings - that last `\r` might just be part of $NF and if you do `print $NF, "foo"` without it you would be printing the wrong string for $NF as it'd be missing the `\r` it had in the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119128/discussion-between-paul-pedant-and-ed-morton).